# Javascript: Callback is not a function

Tags: javascript

roll() function working nice, but when i'm trying to get callback it's throws error: callback is not a function

```
var speed = 300;
function roll(callback) {
  if (typeof callback === "function") {
    console.log('callback is function!'); //yes
  }
  if (speed < 1000) {
    speed += 50;
    setTimeout(roll, 1000); //increase speed
  } else if (speed >= 1000) {
    console.log('finished');
    return callback(true); //problem here?
  }
}
roll(function(callback) {
  console.log(callback); //callback is not a function
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Root cause of problem is here: `setTimeout(roll, 1000)`.

`roll` is being invoked *but* **without** `callback` function by the `setTimeout`.

```js
var speed = 300;

function roll(callback) {
  console.log('callback', callback);
  if (speed < 1000) {
    speed += 50;
    setTimeout(function() { 
      roll(callback); //pass the callback
    }, 1000); //increase speed
  } else {
    console.log('finished');
    callback(true); //removed un-wanted `return`
  }
}
roll(function(result) { //renamed parameter
  console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When this portion of the code fires, `roll` is not given a `callback` parameter:

```
setTimeout(roll, 1000); //increase speed
```

So when this part of the code is executed:

```
return callback(true); //problem here?
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`callback` is `undefined` and therefore is not a `function`. You can avoid getting this error by doing something like this:

```
else if (speed >= 1000) {
    console.log('finished');
    if(typeof callback === 'function'){
        return callback(true);
    }else{
        // do what you want here if callback is undefined
    }
}
```